# Retrieve relationships between child nodes using neo4j cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

[image]

I have a following network result when I run this query in neo4j browser:

```
MATCH (n1:Item {name: 'A'})-[r]-(n2:Item) Return n1,r,n2
```

At the bottom of the graph, it says: `Displaying 6 nodes, 7 relationships`.
But when I look on the table in the neo4j browser, I only have 5 records

```
n1,r,n2
A,A->B,B
A,A->C,C
A,A->D,D
A,A->E,E
A,A->F,F
```

So in the java code, when I get the list of records using the code below:

```
List<Record> records = session.run(query).list();
```

I only get 5 records, so I only get the 5 relationships.
But I want to get all 7 relationships including the 2 below:

```
B->C
C->F
```

How can i achieve that using the cypher query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
MATCH (n:Item {name: 'A'})-[r1]-(n2:Item)
WITH n, COLLECT(r1) AS rs, COLLECT(n2) as others
UNWIND others AS n2
OPTIONAL MATCH (n2)-[r2]-(x)
WHERE x IN others
RETURN n, others, rs + COLLECT(r2) AS rs
```

Unlike @FrantišekHartman's first approach, this query uses `UNWIND` to bind `n2` (which is not specified in the `WITH` clause and therefore becomes unbound) to the same `n2` nodes found in the `MATCH` clause. This query also combines all the relationships into a single `rs` list.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to achieve this. One ways is to travers to 2nd level and check that the 2nd level node is in the first level as well

```
MATCH (n1:Item {name: 'A'})-[r]-(n2:Item)
WITH n1,collect(r) AS firstRels,collect(n2) AS firstNodes
OPTIONAL MATCH (n2)-[r2]-(n3:Item)
WHERE n3 IN firstNodes
RETURN n1,firstRels,firstNodes,collect(r2) as secondRels
```

Or you could do a Cartesian product between the first level nodes and match:

```
MATCH (n1:Item {name: 'A'})-[r]-(n2:Item)
WITH n1,collect(r) AS firstRels,collect(n2) as firstNodes
UNWIND firstNodes AS x
UNWIND firstNodes AS y
OPTIONAL MATCH (x)-[r2]-(y)
RETURN n1,firstRels,firstNodes,collect(r2) as secondRels
```

Depending on on cardinality of firstNodes and secondRels and other existing relationships one might be faster than the other.